# PHPStorm: correct PHPDoc for a Collection of Objects?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using the [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDE, and run into trouble when I run the code inspection.

I have a method which returns a collection of objects. The `Collection` itself is an object, which has its own methods, and implements the [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface:

```php
class Repository
{
    public function findByCustomer(Customer $user)
    {
        // ...
        return new Collection($orders);
    }
}
```

If I document `findByUser()` to return a `Collection`, the code inspection understands the methods on this object, but doesn't understand what objects the collection contains:

```php
/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function findByCustomer() { ... }
```

[image: Method getTotal() not found in class Collection]

If I document `findByUser()` to return a collection of `Order` objects, the code inspection now understands what's inside the collection, but not the methods on the `Collection` itself:

```php
/**
 * @return Order[]
 */
public function findByCustomer() { ... }
```

[image: Method slice() not found in class Order[]]

Is there a way to specify both at the same time, something like Java's syntax?

```php
/**
 * @return Collection<Order>
 */
public function findByCustomer() { ... }
```

Comment: You can combine them (both types) together. May not be ideal in some situations, but works and you may consider it better than manually specifying type via @var PHPDoc comment. So ... `/** @return Collection|Order[] */`

Comment: @LazyOne: even if not the perfect one, that's a cleaner option to me. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: @LazyOne - phpstorm complains "Return type does not match the declared "

Comment: @Darius.V Please provide a full code example -- it may show what is missing / where the culprit is. P.S. If you have declared the actual PHP return type for the function, then yes, it may be doing that. Need example that can be easily copy pasted or imported (a simple test project will do).

Comment: @LazyOne I am not able to reproduce it even with Collection declared as return type. But I think it was this, just in different place which I do not remember now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Phpstorm starting from 2021.2 allows the following syntax:

```php
    /**
     * @return Collection<Order>
     */
```

This works for Doctrine Collections - and all Laravel Collections starting with Laravel 9 (the required annotation is not present in L8).

Screenshot from PhpStorm What's New 2021.2:
[image: Screenshot from PhpStorm What's New 2021.2]

Comment: I was waiting for such a feature like since ever...

Comment: This works for Doctrine, but not fo Laravel collections

Comment: Actually the correct syntax should be `Collection<int, Order>` for Doctrine.

Comment: PHPStorm still doesn't have great support for accessing `\ArrayAccess<TKey, TValue>` using regular `$collection[0]` syntax as of 2022.3.2, see related https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61439/Support-generics-for-array-access-type-inference-via-ArrayAccessoffsetGet

Answer (score 70):

You can combine them (both types) together. May not be ideal in some situations, but works and you may consider it better than manually specifying type via `@var` PHPDoc comment.

```
/** @return Collection|Order[] */
```

Comment: In that case it can even read : return Collection than can be seen as an array of Order.

Comment: @Benjamin Please provide some simple code example to copy-paste (I would like to see it myself deeper)

Comment: @LazyOne I'm surprised I can't repeat it now, I had all these inspection issues when I first opened PHPStorm 8. It might not be what I thought, and in fact be related to [WI-22469](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22469) you just commented on!

Answer (score 4):

As MV1908 said, you can use generic collecions in PHPStorm since 2021.2.
However, note that this is only possible for a custom collection class (that you created yourself) and Doctrine collection, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/07/phpstorm-2021-2-release/

With the release of PHPStorm 2021.3 its now possible to use generics also for Laravel Collections (however only for Laravel 9). See https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/12/phpstorm-2021-3-release/#support_for_future_laravel_collections

[image]