# phpdoc variable of class ArrayObject

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a class that extends `ArrayObject`

`class Collection extends ArrayObject`

I know i can define array of objects using this code:

`/* @var $userArray Model_User[] */`

But how can i define variable `$userArray` as an custom array of class `Collection` that contains objects of class `Model_User`?

Without changing `class Collection` or its phpdoc. 
I want to use the same `class Collection` for different arrays of objects.

This is not the same as [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects), because in that subject discussion is related to common arrays in php, which are phpdoced as 
`/* @var $userArray Model_User[] */` in the mean time my question relates to custom build array which if phpdoced my method above will not type hint methods of custom build array class, like so `$userArray->echoChanges()` because it will think its a common array, not an array of class Collection. And yes `$userArray` also acts as an array, so it should type hint array contents `$userArray[3]->name`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

Comment: not even close, my array can have its own functions, like $userArray->resetChanges() so it should type hint + its also acts as an array $userArray[4] ->name and it should type hint as well.

Comment: In other words what your asking is: where `$x = [new Name()];` then `/* @var $x Name[] */` so `$y = new Collection([new Name()]);` then `/* @var $y ? */`

Comment: code will work like this:
`$a = new Collection();
$a[] = new Model_User();
$a->resetChanges();
$a[0]->name = "George";
$a->echoChanges();`

and i dont know how to phpdoc $a, so its knew it has methods of class `Collection` and contains objects of class `Model_User`.

just in case http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayobject.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PSR-5: PHPDoc](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/211063eed7f4d9b4514b728d7b1810d9b3379dd1/proposed/phpdoc.md#collections) proposes a form of Generics-style notation.

## Syntax

```
Type[]
Type<Type>
Type<Type[, Type]...>
Type<Type[|Type]...>
```

Values in a Collection MAY even be another array and even another Collection.

```
Type<Type<Type>>
Type<Type<Type[, Type]...>>
Type<Type<Type[|Type]...>>
```

## Examples

```
<?php

$x = [new Name()];
/* @var $x Name[] */

$y = new Collection([new Name()]);
/* @var $y Collection<Name> */

$a = new Collection(); 
$a[] = new Model_User(); 
$a->resetChanges(); 
$a[0]->name = "George"; 
$a->echoChanges();
/* @var $a Collection<Model_User> */
```

Note: If you are expecting an IDE to do code assist then it's another question about if the IDE supports PHPDoc Generic-style collections notation.

Comment: thx, thats what i was looking for, as for type hinting if anyone needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706835/phpstorm-correct-phpdoc-for-a-collection-of-objects. And also PSR-5 is in a draft status, so it may change.

Comment: In this exemple, what PHPDoc do you apply to Collection and on the ArrayAccess' methods ?