# How to write PHPDoc in PhpStorm to return both PDO and MySQLi connections

Tags: php, return, phpstorm, phpdoc

I've written a function for easier database connections with the ability to connect via PDO or MySQLi options.
Currently I struggle with PHPDov `@return` property.

I've reached the correct highlights of PDO methods in PhpStorm but I don't know how to make work similarly for both options. The code below may explain it better.

Here's my dbCon.php function:

```
<?php

# defining the root directory as constant
define('__ROOT__', dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));

/**
 * @param $db
 * @param $conType
 * @return PDO[]
 */

function dbCon($db, $conType)
{
# parse the data from db.ini where $db is database name
$_con = parse_ini_file(__ROOT__ . '/db.ini');

# set prefix if required by hosting to have one
$pre = 'database_';

# list parameters via variables
$_host = $_con[$db . '_ht'];
$_user = $pre . $_con[$db . '_un'];
$_database = $pre . $_con[$db . '_db'];
$_password = $_con[$db . '_pw'];

# PDO attributes
$_pdo_attr = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING // development mode only
];

# define dbCon variable;
$_dbCon = false;

# set PDO or MYSQLI connection
switch ($conType) {
    case 'pdo':
        try {
            ${$db . '_pdo'} = new PDO ("mysql:host=$_host;dbname=$_database; charset=utf8", $_user, $_password, $_pdo_attr);
            $_dbCon = ${$db . '_pdo'};
            $_dbSts = ${$db . '_pdo'}->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $_dbSts = false;
        }
        break;
    case 'mysqli':
        ${$db . '_mysqli'} = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_database);
        if (${$db . '_mysqli'}->connect_error) $_dbSts = false;
        else $_dbSts = explode('  ', mysqli_stat(${$db . '_mysqli'})); $_dbCon = ${$db . '_mysqli'};
        break;
    default:
        $_dbSts = false; // error case
        break;
}
# output
return ["dbSts" => $_dbSts,
        "dbCon" => $_dbCon];
}
```

So, as you can see by..

```
/**
 * @param $db
 * @param $conType
 * @return PDO[]
*/
```

..this works well for returning the PDO array but as the function allow to switch to MySQLi I'd like those methods to be highlighted as well.

Comment: Why do you need both at the same time? They will have different method signatures etc. Just stick to one or use separate methods to create different connection handlers. In any case: just as @Mark said -- use `\PDO[]|\MySQLi` kind of stuff -- it means that either of these types is possible (on related note: not to answer your question directly, but to give you some idea on how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717583/783119) . PHPDoc PSR draft: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#511-return

Comment: The idea behind was just to write a sigle function where I change only one parameter (`$conType` in my case) and use different methods if needed. As you can see function returns only one connection at a time depens on the `$conType`

Comment: *"The idea behind was just to write a sigle function where I change only one parameter ($conType in my case) and use different methods if needed."* That's exactly why it's bad. You will understand it with time and will appreciate using simple functions (that do just thing) over complex ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your function to return more than one type just put a pipe between them. I don't know what the specific return type of mysqli is but you're going to want something like this

```
@return PDO[]|MySQLi
```

https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html

Comment: yeah, thank you -- turns out it is precisely important to type `MySQLi` and not just `mysqli` as I tried before and + in my case it's also an array, so `PDO[]|MySQLi[]` works well now

Comment: url is down go to:
https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html